# PHP preg_replace_callback match string but exclude urls

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace-callback

What I'm trying to do is find all the matches within a content block, but ignore anything that is inside  tags, for use inside preg_replace_callback().

For example:

```
test
<a href="test.com">test title</a>
test
```

In this case, I want the first line to match, and the third line to match, but NOT the url match, nor the title match in between the a tags.

I've got a regex that I feel like is close:

```
#(?!<.*?)(\btest\b)(?![^<>]*?>)#si
```

(and this will not match the url part)

**But how do I modify the regex to also exclude the "test" between a and /a?**

Comment: `and the fourth line to match` Erm, you only have three lines in your input?

Comment: Do you have to account for nested tags as well? Eg `<a>test<b>test</b>test</a>`, or self-closing tags? Sounds like a job for something that's *not* a regular expression (HTML and regex generally do not work well together)

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: It doesn't use nested tags, and unfortunately due to the application I have to use regex, but I appreciate the thoughtful question and suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the same pattern you can use [A-Z] or a combination like [A-Za-z]

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving it myself. This regex pattern will do what I wanted:

```
#(?!<a[^>]*?>)(\btest\b)(?![^<]*?<\/a>)#si
```